# F# - How to access function parameters that have no name?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

The function below compiles and runs fine.

I do not intend to create them like this (without parameter names).
However because it lets me create such a function, I am curious how I can access them within the function.

```
let testfunction string int = 
    printfn "Inside Method"

testfunction "a" 5
```

**Here is the F# interactive output**

Inside Method
val testfunction: string: 'a -> int: 'b -> unit
val it: unit = ()

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `string` and `int` are the parameter names, so you access them like any other parameters:

```ml
let testfunction string int = 
    printfn $"string is {string}"
    printfn $"int is {int}"

testfunction "a" 5
```

Output is:

```
string is a
int is 5
```

To reduce confusion, you could declare the function like this:

```ml
let testfunction (string : string) (int : int) = 
    printfn $"string is {string}"
    printfn $"int is {int}"
```